# Validating ARM template returns InvalidResourceName:

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have a few valid ARM templates that I've deployed using PowerShell.  I'm looking to create a DevOps pipeline to run an Azure Deployment task. I have it set for 'Validation Only'.  When I run my pipeline I receive a number of errors similar to:

`"message": "Resource name [concat(parameters('my_env'), 'WEB-LB')] is invalid. The name can be up to 80 characters long....`

It looks like I'm getting one level of function evaluation. Some of these resource names are used in copies, so are concatenated inline with an index.

I believe my service connection has permissions to all the resources in question (which took a few rounds).

I've shortened some of these parameter names to get under the 80 character limit mentioned in the error.

I've tried swapping some parameters for functions.

So I define my template with something like:

```
"parameters": {
   "my_env": {
      "defaultValue": "SBX",
      "type": "string"
   },
   "loadBalancers_GIS_LB_name": {
      "defaultValue": "[concat(parameters('my_env'), 'GIS-LB')]",
         "type": "string"
      },
...
},
"resources": [
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
  "name": "[parameters('loadBalancers_GIS_LB_name')]",
   ...
```

I expect that my template is valid, as I can run it from PowerShell succesfully.

**Update** I've created a [bare-bones template](https://gist.github.com/jhevenor/fcd508d59e39f3772e53f9301f2da8ab). My pipeline validates this template!

Continuing, I added a parameters file which gives the default values for a couple variables.  The pipeline will fail this with the errors shown above. Progress!

Comment: nothing looks wrong with the code. can you share a repro?

Comment: I can look at paring this down to the smallest failing example.  I just find it so off that the error message has the function defined by _loadBalancers_GIS_LB_name_, but that it itself wasn't evaluated.